# Crash on calling free()

Tags: c, linux, crash, fopen, fclose

I don't understand why the following piece of code make my programm crash. 'fp' isn't modified after doing 'fopen()'.

```
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    int len = 0;
    int read;
    char filePath[100] = "";

    //Quick concatenate, I should use concatain but nah.
    snprintf(filePath,sizeof(filePath), "%s/%s/%s",FOLDER_MAIN, "test", "data.txt");
    fp = fopen(filePath, "r");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
        {
            if(startsWith(line, "value:"))
            {
                removeSubstring(line, "value:");
                removeSubstring(line, " ");
                removeSubstring(line, "\t");
                removeSubstring(line, "\n");
                printf("%d\t%s\n", 0, line);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);

        //Free line pointer, is it really needed ?
        if (line)
           free(line);
    }

int StartsWith(const char *a, const char *b)
{
   if(strncmp(a, b, strlen(b)) == 0)
       return 1;

   return 0;
}

void removeSubstring(char *s,const char *toremove)
{
    while( s=strstr(s,toremove))
        memmove(s,s+strlen(toremove),1+strlen(s+strlen(toremove)));
}
```

EDIT:
Also, 'free(line)' make also the programm crash.
I added removeSubstring and StartsWith function, I hope it helps. Anyway, I don't think it impact much on the programm, since the problem is with fp...

Comment: *is it really needed?* - how can one answer that without seeing the declaration of `line`?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] to show the whole life of `line`. Is it initialised? Is it malloced? Is it already freed? ...

Comment: Does it crash if you delte the line with free? If not, please change the title to "crash on free()".

Comment: Sorry, Ajay, I have added the variables. Yunnosch, it's done. Everything is decleared, initialised and malloced.

Comment: Do not promise. Prove. Show. MCVE, please.

Comment: you need to initialize len

Comment: Take a look by yoursefl, all the code is there.

Comment: Some user: Shouldn't change much, but I did that. Still crash.

Comment: Okay, so you __do__ need to free the buffer allocated by `getline`. So that part is okay and you have done it correctly. Now unless `removeSubstring` or `startsWith` are macros that modify the variable `line`, I don't see a reason this should crash.

Comment: I added removeSubstring and startWith, but normally, it shouldn't affect the fp, does it ?

Comment: Please add sample input and in case you do not remove the function calls, what output is generated.

Comment: You could focus debugging on actual crashes due to free after getline, if you remove the calls to `StartsWith()` and `removeString()` as an experiment. Then "shouldn't affect" is guaranteed.

Comment: Please try what happens, if you call getline just once, instead of in a loop. I.e. try `//while ...`.

Comment: Herm.... I started a new project, pasted my code above, tried again, it worked.

Comment: Do you use a 32 bit or 64 bit OS?

Comment: have you run the code in gdb, stepped through it or even ran it, let it crash and grab the backtrace there. There might be some more information in there to let you know what exactly happened

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3):

Your code is undefined behavior.

The prototype of getline is clear `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`, you must use **correct** type specially when you use pointer !

```
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;
```

The compiler should have warning you.

Comment: While this is absolutely correct, any speculated idea how this can cause the crash on free?

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't like talk about undefined behavior but int is probably 32 bit and size_t 64 bit, so getline produce an out of bound by setting len on the stack that change the value of line.